# How to calculate two variables

Tags: javascript

I need help with multiplying these two values in js

```html
<label> Стая </label>
<select name="one" id="one" onChange="calculatePrice()">
  <option value="20"> Единична </option>
  <option value="30"> Двойна   </option>
  <option value="50"> Луксозна </option>
</select>

<label> Брой нощувки </label>
<select name="two" id="two" onChange="calculatePrice()">
  <option value="1"> Една   </option>
  <option value="2"> Две    </option>
  <option value="2"> Три    </option>
  <option value="3"> Четири </option>
  <option value="5"> Пет    </option>
</select>
```

How can I do it

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: For starters, you certainly can't have two elements with `id="one"` as ids are unique.

Comment: oh yeah sorry i must've pasted it twice the second one should be id two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
function calculatePrice() {
var x = document.getElementById("one").value;
var y = document.getElementById("two").value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = parseInt(x) * parseInt(y)
}
```

```html
<label>Стая</label>
        <select name="one" id="one" onChange="calculatePrice()">
            <option value="20">Единична</option>
            <option value="30">Двойна</option>
            <option value="50">Луксозна</option>
        </select>
<br>
<label>Брой нощувки</label>
        <select name="two" id="two" onChange="calculatePrice()">
            <option value="1">Една</option>
            <option value="2">Две</option>
            <option value="2">Три</option>
            <option value="3">Четири</option>
            <option value="5">Пет</option>
        </select>
        
<hr>
<p>Result:</p>
<span id="result"><em>Select an option to multiply</em></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')

myForm.oninput = () =>
  {
  let sum = parseInt( myForm.one.value )
          + parseInt( myForm.two.value )
          
  console.clear()
  console.log(sum)
  setTimeout( console.clear, 2500);
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; left:70% !important; width:30%; }
.as-console-row { background-color: yellow; }
.as-console-row-code { font-size:3em !important;  padding:1em !important;   }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
.as-console-row::before { content: 'sum:'; font-size: .8em; }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <label> Стая </label>
  <select name="one" >
    <option value="20"> Единична </option>
    <option value="30"> Двойна   </option>
    <option value="50"> Луксозна </option>
  </select>
<br><br>
  <label> Брой нощувки </label>
  <select name="two" >
    <option value="1"> Една   </option>
    <option value="2"> Две    </option>
    <option value="2"> Три    </option>
    <option value="3"> Четири </option>
    <option value="5"> Пет    </option>
  </select>
</form>
```